# Getting the last four characters of a string in FreeMarker

Tags: java, substring, freemarker

I have a FreeMarker variable, `${string}` which can be of any length. How can I get the last four characters only?

For example:

string = "326235253235235";

I want to display: "5235";

Comment: You almost certainly never want to do this. Do you understand the difference between a code point and a Java char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

get the length of the string by `string.length();` then use `substring` to identify where you need to trim from `string` like;

```
string.substring(string.length()-4,string.length());
```

`substring` method usage;

```
string.substring(beginning index,end index);`

so your beginning index is 326235253235235
                                      |



and your end index is 326235253235235
                                    |
```

Comment: I'd suggest checking that string.length()>=4 too, to avoid negative indexes and IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: @Exceptyon since he is sending strings manually, I did not feel to write down that but you are right.

Comment: @user1652920 my pleasure

Comment: This is not in FreeMarker though, but in Java. Also the 2nd argument to `substring` can be omitted in this case.

Comment: Yes there is also that usage but he wanted in that way.

Comment: This answer corresponds to java and not FTL. So this cannot be marked the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

If you do this in the FreeMarker template, `string[string?length-4..]`. Though be sure `string` won't be shorter than 4 characters.